# Creating SQL tables dynamically in a loop

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, dynamic, create-table

I  need to dynamically create X tables. The X is calculated on the fly based on a series of other calculations that get passed in. I've written the following dynamic code in an effort to create a loop and generate a create statement each time.

I can't use global tables for this project.

```
DECLARE @cnt_v varchar(10)
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(max) = ''
DECLARE @season_counter int = 5

    SET @cnt  = 1
    SET @cnt_v  =  CONVERT(varchar(10), @cnt)

     WHILE @cnt <= @season_counter
     BEGIN

    select  @SQL =  @SQL    +   'create table #Season_year'  + @cnt_v + ' (customer_no int, order_no int, order_dt datetime, season_no int)'
    exec    sp_executesql @SQL 

    set     @sql = ''
    select  @SQL =  @SQL    +   'select * from #Season_year'  + @cnt_v 
    exec    sp_executesql @SQL 

    select      @cnt = @cnt + 1
    select      @cnt_v = CONVERT(varchar(10), @cnt)
    select      @sql = ''

    END
```

---

The output of the above code is the following errors

### [image]

When manually create the tables, by typing

`create table #Season_year1 (customer_no int, order_no int, order_dt datetime, season_no int)'`

then use my dynamic loop to insert data, update records and ultimately drop the temp tables everything works without an issue. The problem is solely creating the tables dynamically.

If this approach isn't going to work, how else could I do this?
Thank you

Comment: This is a scope issue.  Temp table evaporate when the thread is completed

Comment: @JohnCappelletti then how do I dynamically build tables without knowing in advance how many tables I need to build.

Comment: Expand your dynamic SQL (you can even have dynamic SQL within dynamic SQL), but I suspect there are better solutions.  Perhaps if you expand on your goal.

Comment: You create a temp table containing no rows and then immediately select from the temp table - generating an empty resultset. That does nothing obviously useful but perhaps you have removed code that demonstrates a real need. Given the name pattern, why not just create a single table with a column for year? No dynamic sql needed at all.

Comment: @SMor yes this is what I currently do. The problem is I've hard coded 8 tables, and I need to grow this to about 15 for this given season. Starting next season it will be 16 years, then 17 etc. I don't have an objections to hard coding it but the hope is to make it dynamic and not touch the code every year.

Comment: And once again - why do you need multiple copies of the same table? Add a "year" column and you don't need dynamic sql at all. Just add the rows for each "year" in the one table. But as already mentioned, you have scoping issues that cause your problem. How to best address that depends on how you use those tables. If you struggle with this, perhaps dynamic sql is not the best path for you.

Comment: @SMor I'm aware of the scoping issue, the question is how to I do this dynamically. The reason I need a year issue has to do with the fact that its not just a year. For each year there are two types of data so theoretically two temp tables and the data is treated differently as are the columns. After which they are both evaluated by a secondary step and then that is imported into a singular table with a row count, order dt etc. Once that is complete more complex dynamic calculations occur. Its like complex code on complex code on two sets of different data.

Comment: The issue here is your design. Creating multiple copies of the same table over and over like this is extremely bad. You will have to constantly be updating your code, not just the code that creates the tables but the code that selects from them as well. Just don't do this to yourself. This question is almost a textbook example of an XY Problem. https://xyproblem.info/

Comment: @SeanLange I read the the xyproblem. Not sure what the implication is. I am asking for help creating tables dynamically. The rest of my code has already been written (creating hard coded since initially only requested 5 years worth of review). The code is complex, it creates these tables, pulls data -- but there is two types of data. Once they have the 10 tables data gets evaluated, and modified etc. Then dynamically does a lot of other steps, etc. Those steps aren't pertinent to the problem. Tables need to be created on the fly based on some growing number then populated, calculated etc.

Comment: Right...you are asking how to do this strange and complicated process which you think is the solution to your issue. My point is that the solution you have devised seems to a less than ideal way of solving whatever it is you are trying to resolve.

Comment: @SeanLange the solution we implemented we spent quite a bit of time researching options, we didn't just pick the first idea and run with it. We have years of purchase history, specific purchase history that falls into two categories. 5 years of purchase history to compare year to year but each year you can purchase type 1 and type 2 it can be done in order 1,2 or 2,1. it may just be one or neither. we compare it year to year. the comparison alone is very complex. I'm not looking to reinvent the wheel just figure out how to dynamically create the tables to track purchases over the years.

Comment: You were shown in the answer below how you could go about doing that. But it sounds like your problem is more complex than just creating the tables. Because you are creating a very complicated set of tables dynamically, everything you do after that is going to be even more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Each one of your dynamic sql statements is run within its own scope, so in the `SELECT * FROM #Season_year5` has no idea what `#Season_year5` is.  In the first dynamic SQL statement it's created and destroyed all with the execution of `sp_executesql`.  If you combine them both into a single dynamic SQL statement then you will be able to access the temp table in other statements.

```
DECLARE @cnt INT = 1;
DECLARE @cnt_v varchar(10)
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(max) = ''
DECLARE @season_counter int = 5

    SET @cnt  = 1
    SET @cnt_v  =  CONVERT(varchar(10), @cnt)

     WHILE @cnt <= @season_counter
     BEGIN

    select  @SQL = @SQL + N'create table #Season_year'  + @cnt_v + N' (customer_no int, order_no int, order_dt datetime, season_no int);
                            select * from #Season_year'  + @cnt_v + N';'
    exec    sp_executesql @SQL 

    select      @cnt = @cnt + 1
    select      @cnt_v = CONVERT(varchar(10), @cnt)
    select      @sql = ''

    END
```

Comment: This is great, but there is a problem with this approach. I take these X tables then evaluate the data inside then drop them into another table -- so I would have to make this dymaic code really long and complex. 

Also what does N mean:   N'create table ...  @cnt_v + N';' at the start and end of your statements?

Comment: If you don't want to generate a big long dynamic SQL statement (which I completely understand) you migth want to switch to physical tables instead of temp tables.  The `N` means treat the string literal as `NVARCHAR` which is what `sp_executesql` takes as the parameter type.